# Scale on y axis with Gadfly

Tags: julia

I have a small issue with Gadfly, I want to plot the tension of a sensor over the time but the scale on the y axis is too wide and I can't expaned it. Already looked through the gadfly documentation without finding an answer.

For the following julia code,

```
b=plot(x=time,y=lambda,Guide.xlabel("Temps"),Geom.line,Coord.Cartesian(ymin=0.28,ymax=1.0,xmin=0,xmax=150),Guide.ylabel("Lambda"),Guide.title("Evolution lambda en fonction du temps"),Scale.y_continuous(scalable=false))
```

I get something like this,

[image: O2 sensor voltage]

But here I only have on the y axis: 0.5 , 1.0 and I want more like 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,... because it is not readable that way.

Anyone knows how I would do that with gadfly?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: PS: I want more values on the y-axis but I don't want to change the scale itself on that axis

Comment: Is [Guide.yticks](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/guides/guide_yticks.html) what you want?